# Android Ringtone change intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know whether there is an intent(like "android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED"-notifies when a wallpaper has been changed)  that would notify my broadcast receiver ***when a ringtone has been changed*** or a **when a new ringtone has been set**.

If there isn't Is there any other way to notify my BroadcastReceiver that the ringtone has been changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intent for something like "RINGTONE_CHANGED":
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I wonder if that's possible without hacking into the Android-system, especially as a change of ringtones will not always mean the the "system"-ringtone has been changed (as with the wallpaper), e.g. you can change a ringtone just for one contact ... so as there's no event you can connect to, I would guess, the answer is: no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I guess i would need to use a service with an alarm and check the ringtone at intervals to see whether the ringtone has changed although this is a workaround.